# Pre-commit hook for Java Project

Tags: java, git, github, devops, githooks

is it possible to set pre-commit hook for java & pom based project? I came across blog https://dwmkerr.com/conventional-commits-and-semantic-versioning-for-java/ and able setup commit-msg and he mentioned the command "git config core.hooksPath .githooks" it will work but each developer needs to manually run the command. is there any other way to make automated process?

Answer (score 1):

> it will work but each developer needs to manually run the command

That is the problem with [client-side hooks](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#_client_side_hooks): there is always an "activation" to be set by the user.

I know only of one "semi-automatic" way to setup such hooks: using a [template directory](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-init#_template_directory) which can be referenced by a [`git clone`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#Documentation/git-clone.txt---templatelttemplate-directorygt).

*Then* you would get a repository with addition hooks already in place.